# Why spark dataframe.take throw an exception incompatible type?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was try this in Java:

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read()
                .format("avro")
                .load("mysource_path");

Row[] rows = df1.selectExpr("sum(distance) as total").take(1);
```

and the compiler says:

```
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Row[]
        Row[] rows = df1.selectExpr("sum(distance) as total").take(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java the take method returns an Object despite the intellisense says that is Row[].

To solve I did:

```
Row[] rows = (Row[])df1.selectExpr("sum(distancia) as total").take(1);
```